# Cannot ping a device with an IP

Tags: lan, ip, ping

I have a device (an handheld gauge with display) that has a ethernet cable allow transfer of data to the computer. I wired the ethernet cable to the computer. The device can ping itself to be 100.0.0.1, but on my computer terminal when I try to ping 100.0.0.1, I receive 100% data lost as if the computer is not connected to the device, but I'm sure the LAN cable has been connected. How come the device cannot be pinged?

Comment: Have you set your local IP address to something like 100.0.0.2 to allow you to ping it? the ip's need to be on the same subnet.

Comment: how can I set the subnet? Now the device has an IP of 100.0.0.1. So i manually set my IP as 100.0.0.2. I try pinging myself locally 100.0.0.2 and already I get 100% packet lost. How can I even ping my own IP?

Comment: @KMC How did you set "my IP"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, the devices need to be on the same subnet.  Can you set the subnet n the handheld device?  It will be something likek 255.255.0.0 but there are many variants If you can, also change the IP on the handheld to something that is not routable.  100.0.0.1 can give issues.  Your 100.0.0.1 address is owned by verizon and most systems will try and route traffic out to the Internet to find that address. Can you use 10.X.X.X or even 192.168.X.X and use a submet mask of 255.255.255.0  The handheld and teh PC will need to be set up on the same subnet so for example

Handheld
IP 192.168.1.5
Subnet 255.255.255.0

PC
IP 192.168.1.6
Subnet 255.255.255.0

gateway is not important.

Depending on the device, you may need a crossover cable if connecting from handheld to PC.  If you connect both to a switch or a hub, a regular cable is fine.

Answer (score 4):

IP has the concept of subnets. If a destination IP address is on a different subnet the computer will use a router to get the data to the other subnet. Your computer thinks the device is in a different subnet, not local.

Comment: how do I set it to the same subnet?

Comment: The IP is a "real" routable IP which adds to the problem.

Comment: @DaveM I was under the impression that all IPs were just logical addresses, didn't know some were "real".

Comment: I think he means it's a publicly routable address and not a private one. the 192.168.1.x range and 10.69.10.x would be an example of a private IP. You probably know this but I am just dropping it here for general knowledge.

Comment: @Kyle You are correct sir. Any insight as to why he would think that would "add to the problem"? I certainly don't how it would since this person is simply using a Point-to-Point link.

Comment: I think the point is that the users pc almost definitely doesn't have a public IP and thus is not on the same subnet.

Answer (score -3):

I believe it is because the packets are not being routed. You need some sort of routing device between the computer and the gauge.

Is the device fixed to that specific IP address? If not, if you have an internet "modem", and that is connected to a router, connect there. If the router only has one port, you will need an ethernet hub.

You will also need to access your router and tell it to share IP addresses. It's not as complicated as it sounds.

I'm sure others will give you more specific advice. It would be helpful though if you described your network configuration.

Comment: You're...making this waaaay more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: +1: I don't know why people downvote you. The device has a fixed IP that is factory reset, so it is not acting as a modem. The LAN cable is a patch type, not a cross type because the device is not a computer. My computer and device are different device. How to ping it while my LAN cable is directly connected to the device?

Comment: @holocryptic, and how did your comment help?

Comment: @KMC, I still believe my answer is correct. I do not think you can send packets- i.e., Ping - to a device by just using an ethernet cable. Maybe I'm wrong, but I've never been able to do this, with network printers, with IP Cameras, nor with Scanners.

Comment: No router is needed and as the IP is one that is owned by verizon, the user cannot set up routing. They just need to be on the same subnet and one that is not routable would be best

Comment: @KMC, I hope your problem is solved. I was trying to help. Apparently, I dug myself a hole.. Oh well.